# Clear previous command output (not full screen)

Tags: terminal, shell, perl, terminal.app

## Example

This is on the terminal screen:

```
user@host ~ % ls
dir1
dir2
dir3

user@host ~ % whoami
user

user@host ~ % date
Wed May 24 16:25:26 -03 2023

user@host ~ % [CURSOR IS HERE]
```

I'm trying to implement a way to clear only the output from the las command (in the example `date`) . It could be a script (I'm trying with bash/zsh and perl) or a shortcut.

So after that, continuing with the example, we should see:

```
user@host ~ % ls
dir1
dir2
dir2

user@host ~ % whoami
user

user@host ~ % [CURSOR IS HERE]
```

If I do it again it should delete `whoami`:

```
user@host ~ % ls
dir1
dir2
dir2

user@host ~ % [CURSOR IS HERE]
```

On Terminal.app (macOS) there is a shortcut `cmd+L` (*Clear to previous mark*)

I think it's handy for some situations. And after a exhaustive search I couldn't find a way to implement it other terminal emulators.

The close I could get is this. I gave up trying but may be on the right track:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "\e[1F\e[0J";
```

```
# zsh function
function clear_until_previous_command() {
  local previous_output_lines=$(( $(tput lines) - $(fc -l -1 | wc -l) ))
  echo -ne "\033[${previous_output_lines}F\033[0J"
}
```

But both clear the whole screen.

I'm on Alacritty but I think it is possible to make a portable solution for this task?

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that the Marks concept is unique to the macOS terminal.